# Как правильно строить приложения в angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

У меня есть исходная страница (index.html) где имеется несколько . Такие как header, footer, slider, content. Я использую их чтобы разделять страницы на части и заменять другим представлением при переходе.

Но я столкнулся с рядом проблем, если создать header.html и добавить  (Я делаю это чтобы изменять дизайн шапки на разных страницах) то перестает нормально работать меню на мобильной версии.

Так же появились разные проблемы со всеми jquery/javascript функционалом который лежит в ui-views. К примеру owl-slider перестал вообще работать.

Как правильно разделять angularjs приложения и как сделать чтобы не angularJS функционал работал?

Comment: Если я всё правильно понял, то проблема у Вас с тем, что не корректно работает JS. Это уже связано с тем, что все JS компоненты надо заменить на аналогичные для AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема в том, что вы запускаете выполнение не angular скриптов до того, как dom отрендерился. В Angular можно использовать `$timeout`

```
$scope.gallery = {...};
$timeout(function(){
    // запускаем карусель
});
```

Без указания времени таймаута он будет срабатывать когда отрендерится dom.

С меню и прочим, нужно вешать ивенты на `document`.